# What is the longest time a football team has gone without being behind?

Tags: football, trivia

Meaning, being in a winning or drawing position.
For context, if a team won but was behind during the game it doesn't count.
1. In the top 5 leagues?
2. In any league, if this information exists?

Comment: Does not being behind in the home league but being behind in the Champions League in between count?

Comment: And does it count between seasons or only within the same season? And what about national or regional cup games within the season?

Comment: All counts. No restrictions except friendlies.